# ssrs matrix not sorting and not getting other months

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have a dataset like
[image]

I am creating a matrix to represent the data like this-
  [image]

The problem is since I don't have other months (Mar-Dec) in the Dataset, I'm getting for first two months only (Also not in order). I'm new to SSRS and your help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you can use PIVOT in stored procedure to make the matrix data, it will be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation. My solution was to include every month in my dataset, by using UNION and CROSS JOIN. Use CROSS JOIN to include all the possible combination of Department and Month, regardless whether you have data or not, but set their Amount to be 0. Like this:

You_Original_SELECT_Statement
UNION
SELECT D.Department, M.Month, 0 AS Amount
FROM Month M CROSS JOIN Department D

Comment: I was going to suggest left joining the data onto the full month list, but this would also work.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Month` Group Properties / Sorting tab add this expression:

```
Switch(
Fields!Month.Value="Jan",1,
Fields!Month.Value="Feb",2,
Fields!Month.Value="Mar",3,
Fields!Month.Value="Apr",4,
Fields!Month.Value="May",5,
Fields!Month.Value="Jun",6,
Fields!Month.Value="Jul",7,
Fields!Month.Value="Aug",8,
Fields!Month.Value="Sep",9,
Fields!Month.Value="Oct",10,
Fields!Month.Value="Nov",11,
Fields!Month.Value="Dec",12
)
```

Also set `A-Z` in `Order` setting.

Comment: This sort the Month (Jan,Feb etc.) but other months are not appearing like Mar, Apr, May...

Comment: @Paul, If the months are appearing or not isn't a problem. the expression will sort only the present months.